# Query Data From Two Tables + One Table Must Only Query Using Most Recent Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

ok, I have one table that I'm querying that has historical data in it that is updated every minute or so.  I am pulling the most recent data from it by VehicleKey using the following:

```
SELECT p.VehicleKey, p.Timestamp, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, p.Speed
FROM AVLVehiclePosition p,
    (SELECT max(Timestamp) as maxtime, VehicleKEy
      FROM AVLVehiclePosition
      GROUP BY VehicleKey) maxresults  
WHERE p.VehicleKey = maxresults.VehicleKEy  
AND p.Timestamp = maxresults.maxtime
```

I need to also pull some related information from a second table and return it with the results of the above query.  I have figured out how to pull the related data by VehicleKey for EVERY instance of the VehicleKey:

```
SELECT p.Timestamp, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, p.Speed, v.Name, v.VehicleKey
FROM AVLVehiclePosition p, Vehicle v
WHERE p.VehicleKey = v.VehicleKey
```

Now I don't know what to do to combine the two queries to where I'm pulling v.Name for ONLY the most recent results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another JOIN to the existing query that you have.  And it's a lot cleaner when you use an explicit (INNER) JOIN matching keys in the ON clause, compared with an inferred CROSS JOIN (using comma separated tables) that are filtered in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT p.VehicleKey, p.Timestamp, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, p.Speed, v.Name
FROM AVLVehiclePosition p
JOIN Vehicles v
  ON p.VehicleKey = v.VehicleKey
JOIN (SELECT max(Timestamp) as maxtime, VehicleKEy
      FROM AVLVehiclePosition
      GROUP BY VehicleKey) maxresults  
  ON p.VehicleKey = maxresults.VehicleKEy  
  AND p.Timestamp = maxresults.maxtime
```

And you can make this even cleaner if you make use of ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH maxResults AS (
  SELECT p.VehicleKey, p.Timestamp, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, p.Speed, v.Name,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.VehicleKey ORDER BY p.Timestamp DESC) rowNum
  FROM AVLVehiclePosition p
  JOIN Vehicles v
    ON p.VehicleKey = v.VehicleKey)
SELECT * FROM maxResults
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The second is much cleaner, I will have to figure out what it all means.

Comment: You're using rowNum = 1 because it will be the most current row once you sort by p.Timestamp DESC?

Comment: Correct, it's the first row when ordered by Timestamp (in descending order) for each VehicleKey

Comment: Although the code in the second query does look cleaner, it takes almost twice as long to execute as the first query (15 seconds opposed to 8).  I truly wish I was fluid enough in SQL to understand how the logic works with them.

Comment: You _do_ have an index on VehicleKey and Timestamp for your `AVLVehiclePosition` table, right?  If so, please post the query plan.  If not, _make one_.  Also, how many rows does this table contain?

Comment: No, I do not have an index on VehicleKey and Timestamp.  I'm not the owner of the table, I'm just querying the already created tables to grab information for webmapping purposes.

The table has 2+ million rows and counting...

Comment: Umm, with this much unindexed data, any query you build to get the data you need is bound to be slow. And it will get even slower as more data builds.  Not much can be done about this - I would recommend perhaps asking the table owner(s) to make one...  Alternatively, migrate the data (in batches) to a table under your control that you are able to index.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into what it will take to get the vendor to agree to setting up the index or allowing me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join between the two queries:

```
SELECT p.VehicleKey, p.Timestamp, p.Latitude, p.Longitude, p.Speed, v.name
FROM AVLVehiclePosition p
    inner join
    (SELECT max(Timestamp) as maxtime, VehicleKEy
      FROM AVLVehiclePosition
      GROUP BY VehicleKey) as maxresults on p.VehicleKey = maxresults.VehicleKEy and p.Timestamp = maxresults.maxtime
    inner join (
     SELECT name, VehicleKey
     from Vehicle) as v ON maxresults.VehicleKey = v.VehicleKey
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the response.